# How would I go about adding together numbers within the same string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, function, variables, integer

If I have the string "5246-9346-7341-8534" already set as a variable (cardOne) is there a more efficient way to add all of the numbers in that string together than typing out console.log(5 + 2 + 4 + 6 + 9 + etc. . .)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the dashes, do a loop over all the characters, parse them as integers, and add them up.

```
var s = "5246-9346-7341-8534";
var sum = 0;
var i;
s = s.replace(/-/g, "");
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(s.substr(i, 1));
}
console.log(s, "=", sum); // 74
```

(I didn't just do your homework for you, did I?)

Comment: Thank you, the lesson set I was told to finish didn't cover this. Maybe I'm doing more than I'm supposed to. Also no this is like 1/50th of the project but the only part that seemed like I was being wasteful.

Answer (score 4):

You can:

1. Remove all non-digits with [`replace(/\D/g, "")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) (`\D` = "not a digit")
2. Split the string into individual characters with [`split("")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
3. Add together the digits in the array via [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
4. Convert each digit to a number (several ways, one of which is the unary `+`) before adding them together

Example:

```js
var cardOne = "5246-9346-7341-8534";
var sum = cardOne
  .replace(/\D/g, "")        // #1
  .split("")                 // #2
  .reduce(function(x, y) {   // #3
    return +x + +y;          // #4 (twice)
  });
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the hyphens - iterate through the string and add the parsed Number to a total - display the total (74). Note that I added this to an input so that you could add a button and create a named function that allows you to add other numbers.

```js
function addMe(){
  var inputVal = document.getElementById('inputNumber').value.replace(/-/g,'');
var newTotal = 0;
for(i=0;i<inputVal.length;i++){
 newTotal += parseInt(inputVal[i]);
  }
console.log('total = ' + newTotal);
  //gives 74 in this instance
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="5246-9346-7341-8534" id="inputNumber"/>
<button type = "button" onclick="addMe()"> Add Values</button>
```